# Problems in ubuntu 16.04 with alfa AWUS036AC USB WIFI adapter in the power up sequence

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb

I have a problem with alfa AWUS036AC USB WIFI adapter I have installed the correct drivers to used (sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms) but when I power up the computer the usb wifi-adapter is not working I need to unplug and plug the usb wifi-adapter and then works. How can I solve that?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Add **8812au** in this file **/etc/modules** to force the load in boot time.